# Opera tab groups in Firefox 4 Beta?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

I realize Firefox 4 is still beta, but I'm wondering if anyone knows of an addon which will allow you to group tabs as in Opera's tab "stacking". I find this much nicer than Firefox's tab "groups".

For more details, see [this link](http://arstechnica.com/software/news/2010/11/hands-on-opera-11-tab-stacking-vs-Firefox-panorama.ars).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [`PRE` version of *Tab Utilies*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-utilities/versions/?page=1#version-1.2pre17) you can do this.

Some of the settings are hidden though, and you need to go into `about:config` and then in the filter bar type in `extensions.tabutilities.` and you will find in there settings for the stacking and auto-stacking.

Comment: Of course, by now I'm no longer running on 4 Beta, but rather 10 Beta.  B)